# HttpWebRequest Connection Refused get URI

Tags: c#, redirect, httpwebrequest

I make a simple httpwebrequest that gets redirected TWICE. The first redirect redirects me to a site which gives me another redirect. But the uri of the second redirect doesn't exists (it's localhost), so an connectionrefused exception occures. Is there any possibility to get the uri of the second redirect? or just allow one redirect?

Comment: You might want to turn off automatically following redirects entirely with the `AllowAutoRedirect` property.

Comment: But I need the first redirect! And I can't figure out how I can do this :(

Comment: You could follow the first redirect manually...

Comment: @jon I tired this, but it doesn't set the right cookies then! I think  I have to try again